# hline not shown in pdf

Tags: hhline

I'm using the following code but for some of the rows hlines are not shown. Appreciate if anyone can help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{white}

\tcbset{tab3/.style=
{enhanced,colframe=Gray!50!black,colback=white,colupper=black!50!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,nobeforeafter,center title}}

\begin{document}
\tcbox[tab3,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0mm,
toptitle=0.5mm,bottomtitle=0.5mm,title=Test]{%
\arrayrulecolor{black!50!black}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
One & Two & Three \\\hline\hline
Men & Mice & Lions \\\hline
True & False & True \\\hline
Men1 & Mice2 & Lions2 \\\hline
Men1 & Mice2 & Lions23 \\\hline
Upper & Middle & Lower
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: try to delete aux file and recompile. Also, if you have an old version of latex, update (I use 2016 and it is ok)

Comment: This is a known viewer issue, at certain zoom levels the lines disappear and at some other levels they appear, try with another PDF viewer and check if you encounter the same issues.

Comment: What is this strange rule colour – black attenuated by 50% black? A tribute to painter Pierre Soulages? ;o)

Comment: Off-topic: Since you're loading the `xcolor` package with the option `table`, there's no need to load the `colortbl` package separately.